# How does the Asus transformer keyboard dock work?

Tags: hardware, asus-eee-pad-transformer

From a software and hardware standpoint, what kind of interface does the keyboard use? I'm guessing it's not just a usb-hid interface, or if it is there's something special for the special keys.

If I were to make my own device like that, say based on an Android sbc, what would I have to do to replicate it?

Comment: Why would there need to be something special for the special keys? All the keyboard does is send an integer keycode when a key is pressed, special or otherwise. It's the software that's responsible for turning the keycode into an event such as "insert x" or "return home".

Comment: So then it's just USB-HID with a custom keyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an [I2C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2c) interface. According to [this post on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37866602&postcount=4) `asusdec` is the name of the keyboard dock device. When I `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` on my Transformer, this is what it says about `asusdec`:

```
I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="asusdec"
P: Phys=/dev/input/asusdec
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/tegra-i2c.1/i2c-1/1-0019/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=20003
B: KEY=3fffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: LED=2
```

Also, `ps` shows a `com.asus.keyboard` process running as `system`. That's an Android process. I'm not sure how exactly it's getting the input from the keyboard, though. I assume it has sufficient permissions to open the device for reading and converts the incoming keycodes to Android events.